# grep last word of a given line .csv file

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep

I have a text file like this:

```
first, second
hello, bye
one, two
good, bad
day, night
```

I would like to have a script which, based on a variable, retrieves the last word of a given line using `grep` or `awk`.

for example: if num is `3`, output should be `two`.

It's not necessary to ask for num's value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v num="$num" 'NR == num { print $NF }' data.in
```

Testing it:

```
$ num=3
$ awk -v num="$num" 'NR == num { print $NF }' data.in
two
```

The `awk` script reads the input file record by record (a record is by default a line).  Once it hits the record corresponding to the `num` variable, it prints the last field of that record (a field is by default a whitespace-separated column).

The `num` variable inside the `awk` script is an `awk` variable that we initialize to the value of the shell variable `num` with `-v num="$num"` on the command line.

`NR` is the current record number, and `NF` is the number of fields in this record.  `$NF` is the data of the last field.

If your file is strictly comma-separated, add `-F ','` to the command line:

```
$ awk -v num="$num" -F ',' 'NR == num { print $NF }' data.in
```

With `grep` you can't select a specific line, but together with `sed` you can filter out the line you want and then get the last bit after the last comma:

```
$ sed -n "${num}p" data.in | grep -o '[^,]*$'
```

The `sed` bit will get the specified line while the `grep` bit will extract everything after the last comma on that line.

You may do it with `sed` only too:

```
$ sed -n "${num}s/^.*,\(.*\)$/\1/p" data.in
```

Here, the substitution is applied to only the line whose number is `$num`, and it replaces the whole line with the contents of the line after the last comma and outputs the result.  All other output is inhibited with the `-n` command line switch.

Alternatively, use a substitution in `sed` to simply delete everything on the line to the last comma:

```
$ sed -n "${num}s/^.*,//p" data.in
```

Comment: You don’t need `grep` with `sed` in your last example, `sed` can extract the last word too ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt Of course it can (added it). Using `sed` for extracting bits of lines is a bit messy though...

Comment: I agree that extracting tends to get messy, but in this case you can just delete the part you don’t need (`${num}s/^.*,//p`).

Answer (score 1):

In awk, NR is the line number, NF is the number of columns, so $NF is the last column. FS is the input record separator, `', '` for CSV without quoted commas should be enough.

```
awk -v FS=', ' 'NR==3{print $NF}'
```